# Datepicker doesn't scroll in scrollview

Tags: android, datepicker, scrollview, timepicker

There are datapicker and timepicker in my code.
But I have a problem. ScrollView doesn't scroll datapicker and timepicker. Because of this, I can't put a number on the calendar.

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tlqy.jpg)

Here is my xml-code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/calendar_dialog_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" >

   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/date_time_dialoglinear_layout"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

       <TimePicker
           android:id="@+id/task_time_picker"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/task_date_picker" />

       <DatePicker
           android:id="@+id/task_date_picker"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:layout_height="136dp"
           />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/comment_to_transfer_lable"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
           android:text="Change reason"
           android:textSize="16sp" />

       <EditText
           android:id="@+id/comment_to_transfer"
           android:layout_width="244dp"
           android:layout_height="104dp"
           android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
           android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
           android:inputType="textMultiLine"
           android:maxLines="4" >

           <requestFocus />
       </EditText>
   </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a custom timepicker class, and call this override method:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
{

    // Stop ScrollView from getting involved once you interact with the View
    if (ev.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        ViewParent p = getParent();
        if (p != null){
            p.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```